# Marker To Open Google MAPS Direction

Tags: java, android

I have 3 markers of the location of stores, each with its own position (latitude and longitude),I would like to click on a marker so that it opens up the standard Google MAPS with direction FROM where the current user is TO the destination of the clicked marker, now getting user position is OK, clicking on a marker to display snippet OK but how do I click on the snippet pop out ("click here for directions") to open up Google MAPS that come standard with an Android phone to navigate?

Jave:

```
    static final LatLng ARCADIA = new LatLng(-25.746318, 28.221322999999984);
static final LatLng HATFIELD = new LatLng(-25.7487333, 28.238043199999993);
static final LatLng CENTURION = new LatLng(-25.8602778, 28.189444399999957);
private GoogleMap map;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_locate_store);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);


    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    //map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo( 5.0f ) );

        Marker aracdia = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ARCADIA).title("Arcadia")
                .snippet("Cnr Beatrix & Hamilton Street\n Contacts:\nTel: 076 7533 123\n click-for-directions")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_small)));
        Marker hatfield = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HATFIELD).title("Hatfield").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_small)));
        Marker centurion = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(CENTURION).title("Centurion").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_small)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to click the infowindow and when you click it the standard google map will launch with the location of the marker as the location.

**first you need to add a listener for the infowindow:**

```
 myMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(
  new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker){

    }
  }
);
```

**then then create an intent with Geo-URI inside the infowindowclick:**

```
 myMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(
      new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker){
          String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", marker.getPosition().latitude,marker.getPosition().longitude);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
context.startActivity(intent);
        }
      }
    );
```

Comment: Where exactly do I need to add that, I'm getting an error: The method setOnInfoWindowClickListener(GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener) in the type GoogleMap is not applicable for the arguments (new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){})

Comment: @TwoStarII dont use MapFragment change it to (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

Comment: i would rather stick with what I already have I'm still new to Android development, all I want is to click on the snippet box so that it launches or calls the MAPS application.

Comment: @TwoStarII did you import the OnInfoWindowClickListener??? Cause I think you didny import it.. clrt+Shift+o to fix or highlight the OnInfoWindowClickListener and click import

Comment: Hi, I have done the import, normally I just highlight the error and the import appears but not in this case, anyway I'm getting errors after clicking the snippet box now: 04-25 17:24:05.486: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$10.e(Unknown Source), i wanted to post the entire logcat on the original post but Stackoverflow gives errors of formatting, anyway any ideas?

Comment: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon - i hate it when this happens, anyway let me go through the entire log and find the relevant error